# Did PayPal Just Start Charging Fees?

Tags: united-states, taxes

For the longest time, I've been paid without fees, but now I'm seeing fees starting this month.  The fee is about 4-5% of the transaction.

1. Is this new?
2. For tax purposes, can I report the amount **after the fee**, since this now lowers my income by about 5%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge paypal has always charged 2.9% + $0.30 on regular transactions.  I believe the fee is a little higher if you accept a credit card in person.

You report the full gross income but you also report the fee as a business expense.

Comment: Interesting, as I never *get* that income, so I don't see how I can prove the expense.  Basically, when I get $500 now, I'm only getting about $475 on my statement and PayPal notifies me by email that it debited $25 in a fee.

Comment: That's the proof.

Comment: They didn't at first (when they were venture funded, pre-eBay). But since then, yeah, they charge since the credit card vendors charge...

Comment: @StartUpDev, when I go in to PayPal I can run a report that indicates Gross receipts, fees, and net receipts.  I've had a business account since I can remember, perhaps this is a reporting function restricted to business accounts.  You are paying a fee to PayPal for performing a service for you, that is a business expense.  PayPal sending your proceeds net of fees doesn't negate the existence of the fees.